# How do I specify relative paths in CMAKE?

Tags: cmake

I want to specify a path that is relative to the current directory within CMake and have not been able to find a solution.

My project lies in a path something like:

```
C:/Projects/ProjectA/CMakeLists.txt
```

and I want to specify the name of the relative path of the following directory using the set() command:

```
C:/External/Library
```

In other words, what is the CMake translation of

```
../../External/Library?
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The is almost exactly the same, except that you have allow for CMake to run in another location for "out-of-tree" builds.  You do this by specifying the path relative to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`, which is the directory containing the current CMakeLists.txt file.

```
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../External/Library
```

But, you might want to reconsider, and instead use [`FIND_LIBRARY()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) and [`FIND_FILE()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_file.html) commands to search a set of predefined locations, so that users of your library don't have to keep the same relative structure.

Comment: I should specify that I am trying to point to a VTK install directory. If I run CMake it finds the VTK build directory on my system, however I have placed the install directory on our source control system and want to specifically point to that. Using SET(VTK_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../External/VTK) does not do what I want it to do. Thank you

Comment: In what way does it not do what you want it to do?

Comment: Sorry - When I run CMake (GUI for now) I want the VTK_DIR to be autofilled with my custom external path as opposed to the one it automatically finds from my normal system build. I can manually set it and everything is great - but I want it to be automatically filled so that I can run CMake automatically as part of a build script

Comment: Before you call FindVTK, set the cache variable VTK_DIR like this: `SET(VTK_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" CACHE PATH "VTK dir" FORCE)`

Comment: Thanks! It works well. Since the answer is 5 years ago, do you happen to know whether it is the best answer  for the latest cmake?